# How to Grab All Globals as a Reference in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, global-variables, go-python

I'm working on a project that's written in Go and uses [go-python](https://github.com/go-python/gpython/) to run Python code inside. The way it works is you write `code.py` snippits, then the Go code throws in Global variables to use the internal API.

i.e. `code.py` might look like:

```py
some_api_call() # Linters think some_api_call is not defined, but go-python put it in the global scope
```

This works great, but for modularity I want my `code.py` to import `code_2.py`. Unfortunately, if I do this, `code_2.py` doesn't have acces to the API that the go code manually added to `code.py`'s global scope.

i.e.

`code.py`:

```
import code2.py

code2.run_func()
```

`code2.py`:

```
def run_func():
  some_api_call() # This fails since code2.py doesn't have the API injected
```

I can pass in individual API functions to `code_2.py` manually, but there's a lot of them. It would be easier if I could just pass everything in `code.py`'s Global scope, like `code_2.init(Globals)`. Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried circular importing, but `go-python` doesn't let me import the originally called script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a paramter to `code2.run_func()`, and have `run_func` access api calls through its methods or classmethods.

Something like this.  In `code.py`:

```
import code2.py

class Api:
    @classmethod
    def some_api_call(): ...

code2.run_func(Api)
```

And in `code_2.py`:

```
def run_func(api):
    api.some_api_call()
```

Comment: The API is made in the go side of things, so I would have to recreate the Api class in Python if I did this

Comment: I guess you could do it programatically, by accessing `globals()`. Would be more elegant than copying all globals to another module, which could potentially cause name clashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the built-in method [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) will do the trick

code.py:

```py
import code_2

code_2.init(globals())
```

code_2.py:

```py
def init(other_global_scope):
    for k in other_global_scope:
        globals()[k] = other_global_scope[k]

# code_2.py can now run some_api_call()
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answer, straight copying [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) can cause weird issues (since a global variable modified in one file will alter the other, as well as imports/etc), so if you're fine prefixing every API call with `.api`, this will be much more clean:

Top of `code.py`:

```py
api = lambda: None
for k in globals():
  if k.startswith("__") or k == "api":
    continue
  setattr(api, k, globals()[k])


# api.log("Hello World!")

import code_2.py

code2.run_func(api)
```

Since you build the `api` object at the very beginning of `code.py`, `api` won't have anything except for what was passed in by the go code. You can now do

`code_2.py`:

```py
def run_func(api):
  api.log("Hello World!")
```